# Get this class from a page with jquery and execute a php function

Tags: php, jquery, function

I have in my page for example 5 products and i want to retreat one product on click via jquery.
I have created this jquery code but it updates all products from page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".retrage").click(function () {

      $.ajax({url: '<?php echo base_url("property/retreat/{$property->id}"); ?>',
         data: {id: <?php echo $property->id; ?>},
         type: 'post',
         success: function (output) {
         alert(output);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

The function wil return 1 or 0 based on success or fail.
My question is: How can i get only the curent clicked link, not all links from the page with the same class.

Comment: `{$property->id}`? how's you are getting it. `$(this)` will be your friend in such case.

Comment: i get the property id via php

Comment: your code is confusing, because you are not doing anything with your links, neither taking any values and not updating anything after ajax completion.